# Javascript not working with elements inside modal

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4

I need help.

With bootstrap 3 I made a modal with little form to let administrators/users change the user's password.

I've tried to made the same with bootstrap 4, but I am not be able to execute javascript triggered from anchors or buttons that are inside a modal.

Can you help me??

Example that not working:

```
$('.classFromElement').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    alert('hello world');
});
```

Comment: what happens when you remove `e.preventDefault();` ? can you try removing that and see what happens?

Comment: is the element dynamically added? if so you might need to use event delegation to trigger it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sorry,
I 've seen my error.

I've put the modals before the scripts.
This is the problem. Now is solved.

:(

Answer (score 7):

The modal is probably a **dynamically added** html element. So it is not part of the DOM yet. You have to go around (**delegate** the event) via "document" or "html, body" for new elements that are added after window load. I prefer to use "document" because I had times that even the html or body element wasn't even rendered yet + it has a better performance.

Best option and best performance

```
$(document).on('click','.classFromElement', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    alert('hello world');
});
```

OR... Use 'body, html' (Why both? For browser support, they back each other up)

```
$('body, html').on('click','.classFromElement', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    alert('hello world');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I used to try this and it worked well.

This is when you open the bs modal, then apply event to your button.

```
$('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function () {
    $('.classFromElement').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert('hello world');
    });
})
```